# How to deploy third party nuget packages (dependencies) globally to the server in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, deployment, nuget, .net-core

I have this application that depends on [WindowsAzure.Storage nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/). On my local machine everything works fine. Yet when I deploy it to the server it complains that:

> An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest
>   (ProjectName.deps.json) was not found:    package:
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager', version: '3.2.3'
>   path: 'lib/net40/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll'

Well, it makes sense, because I have not taken this package on the server.

I know I can use [SCD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) via runtime identifiers to have all required assemblies being deployed to the server. But that needs more disk space, because I have more applications to deploy ahead.

How can I install that package globally in the server, so that all deployed applications would find the required assemblies?

Comment: SCD plus .NET IL Linker is a temporary solution, before .NET Native becomes production, https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/30

Answer (score 3):

You can use a runtime package store.  The steps here should get you set up.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/runtime-store